# How to match texture for specific spot on sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I have a sphere and use texture on it. I would like to match texture for a specific spot on the sphere without any stretch, wrapping texture etc. just set my x,y texture to specific coordinate on the sphere. The rest of the sphere should be transparency! Like on the image below :D

[image]

Question. How can I get it? What should I use? Is it custom UVMapp or ShaderMaterial.

Greetings, and thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's the easiest way is to author your model in a content creation tool like Blender and then load it into your app (based on a glTF workflow).

Comment: Probably it will be the easiest way but i have to control texture from threejs :D